# having trouble with this mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT login.id_user
     , username
     , SUBSTRING_INDEX
                ( GROUP_CONCAT
                       ( DISTINCT id_item 
                            ORDER 
                               BY items.ts_created
                       ),",",3
                ) grouped_items 
  FROM login
     , items 
 WHERE login.username LIKE '%%' 
   AND items.id_user = login.id_user 
   AND login.ts_deleted IS NULL 
   AND items.ts_deleted IS NULL 
 GROUP 
    BY login.id_user 
 ORDER 
    BY login.ts_created DESC
```

id like to grab entries from login table that dont have items in the items table also. right now the query i wrote grabs users with 3 most recent items.

i have this query that grabs all users. so i guess im trying to combine the two queries into one.

```
SELECT id_user,username 
FROM login 
WHERE login.ts_deleted IS NULL 
ORDER BY ts_created DESC
```

Comment: If you could please refactor your code so it's not all one line it'd make it much more human-readable

Comment: sorry bout that, edited it for readability

Answer (score 1):

If you want *all* users, you need a `left join` and to be very careful about the `on` clause:

```
SELECT l.id_user, l.username,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT i.id_item ORDER BY i.items.ts_created), ',', 3) as grouped_items 
FROM login l LEFT JOIN
     items i
     ON i..id_user = l.id_user and i.ts_deleted IS NULL 
WHERE l.username LIKE '%%' 
      l.ts_deleted IS NULL 
GROUP BY l.id_user 
ORDER BY l.ts_created DESC
```